# jquery slider with button between the content panels

Tags: jquery, toggle, accordion, slide

I'm having problems with a pretty simple task..

I want to be able to switch between two content panels, but with only ONE button.
I have looked at jqueryUI accordion, but that has a header for every content panel.
i want to have a kind of "button" BETWEEN the two panels, which acts as a toggle and slides to each side, showing/hiding the whole content, while becoming a toggle-button.
actually what i want is EXACTLY a toggle-button like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb2aV.png , but with the "ON" and "OFF" sections being my content, and the "button" itself being the button to switch between those.
EDIT: i made this in paint to show you how i want it to behave http://picload.org/image/cwllcdp/toggle.png

I don't know what to search for... can you quickly  recommend an easy way to do this?

thanks

Comment: So why not just check the value of a button using javascript then show and hide the appropriate div  with the content?

Comment: because the other div should move accordingly. like... all at once... i'm struggling with the position-transition of the button, as well with the concurrent showing/hiding of the panels. isn't there a function that does this by itself?

Comment: So you want the accordion effect but triggered by the toggle?

Comment: exactly. like this: http://picload.org/image/cwllcdp/toggle.png

Comment: Ok, now I see. So when the user clicks the "button" the button slides to basically"reveal" the  content that is to be shown. And wipe away what was shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/pdc3m67z/1/) is a JSFiddle that will roughly do what you asked. You'll need to look into proper sliding transitions if thats something you truly desire, but otherwise, it works fairly well. Plus it should be fairly cross-browser as it requires simple CSS and only jQuery's standard library.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="section-1" class="open">
        <p> Hi, Im section 1! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>
    <button id="btn">Toggle</button>
    <div id="section-2">
        <p>How are you? Im section 2! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div.container div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
}

div.container div.open {
    height: 250px;
    display: block;
}

button {
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('button#btn').on('click', function() {
        $('div#section-1').toggleClass('open');
        $('div#section-2').toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

It isn't the prettiest looking sections, but I was just going for simplest explanation.

Also, whichever section you want open at page load, just add the class `open` manually, so to make `section-2` open instead of `section-1` write

```
<div id="section-2" class="open"></div>
```